# Question involving Bayes' Theorem and Law of Total Probability

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, bayes

Usually I know how to do these problems, but this one stumped me. This is what the problem says:

"Let $D$ denote the event that a person selected randomly from a population has a disease, and suppose $P(D) = 0.0002$.

Let $T$ denote the event that the screening test is positive for a person selected at random.

Suppose the manufacturer claims that the rate of false positives is $0.02$ and the rate of false negatives is $0.01$.

Compute $P(T)$."

So $P(D^c \mid T) = 0.02 \implies P(D \mid T) = 0.98$

And $P(D \mid T^c) = 0.01 \implies P(D^c \mid T^c) = 0.99$

$P(T) = P(T \mid D)P(D) + P(T \mid D^c)P(D^c)$, but I don't know how to find $P(T \mid D)$ or $P(T \mid D^c)$.

$P(T \mid D) = \frac{P(D \mid T)P(T)}{P(D)}$, but this equation has two unknowns.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Totally different hint: **ignore the algebraic notation.**  Consider a population of a million people.  Use the information to *count* the people with and without the disease.  Imagine giving them all the test.  For each group, *count* how many people have a positive result.  Your answer will be the sum of these counts divided by the original million people.

Comment: I would suggest you to add the `self-study` tag to this question as there is no way to distinguish it from an assignment.

Comment: @MatthewGunn

Sorry, I'm still stuck.

$P(D) = P(D \mid T)P(T) + P(D \mid T^c)P(T^c) \implies .0002 = .98P(T) + .01P(T^c) = .98P(T) + .01(1 - P(T)) = .97P(T) + .01 = .0002$

Solving for $P(T)$ gives you a negative value.

Comment: @Joe The problem is that the false positive rate is $P(T|D^c)$ not $P(D^c|T)$. See an update to my answer for the algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along @whuber's suggestion lines, you can create a two by two matrix with either probabilities: 
$$\begin{array}{c|cc|c} &T & T^c  \\ \hline D & P(DT) & P(DT^c) & P(D) \\D^c  &P(D^cT) & P(D^cT^c) &P(D^c) \\ \hline & P(T) & P(T^c) & 1 \end{array} $$

Or equivalently, frequency counts out of a million people
$$\begin{array}{c|cc|c} &T & T^c  \\ \hline D & n(DT) & n(DT^c) & n(D) \\D^c  &n(D^cT) & n(D^cT^c) &n(D^c) \\ \hline & n(T) & n(T^c) & 1,000,000 \end{array} $$
And then use your knowledge of probability to fill out the table.

---

### Edit/Update:

The problem is that the false positive rate is $P(T|D^c)$ *not* $P(D^c|T)$.

The false positive rate is the probability of testing positive given that you *don't* have the disease.
$$ P(T|D^c) = .02$$
The false negative rate is the probability of testing negative given that you *do* have the disease.
$$ P(T^c | D) = .01 $$
Hence we have $P(T | D) = .99$. Now going through some algebra/probability stuff:
$$
\begin{align*}
P(T)&=P(TD^c) + P(TD)\\
&=P(T|D^c)P(D^c)+P(T|D)P(D)\\
&=P(T|D^c)(1-P(D))+P(T|D)P(D)\\
&=.02(1 - .0002) + .99 \cdot .0002\\
&=.020194
\end{align*}
$$
Which matches WHuber

Note: previously I had given you the identity $P(D)=P(D|T^c)P(T^c)+P(D|T)P(T)$, which is true but not useful in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

You're stuck because you are relying on algebra.

**Draw a picture.**  *Every application of Bayes' Theorem works like this.*

Here is the setup.  I chose to show a million people because we will get whole numbers in the end.  Of these, some are diseased.  I put them into a special group as shown.  We are going to move them around--without losing track of any of them--as they get tested.

[image]

Move the people into areas according to their test results: positive or negative.  Some were diseased, some were not.  I have drawn four arrows to chart their movements.

[image]

We know some of the numbers.  For instance, $0.0002$ of those million people, or $200$ of them, are diseased.  The remaining $999,800$ are not.  We also know that one percent of the diseased people will have a false negative and two percent of the disease-free people will have a false positive.  Because these are pretty rare outcomes, I have made their arrows thin.

[image]

Therefore the remaining $0.99$ of the $200$ diseased people will test positive and the remaining $0.98$ of the $999,800$ disease-free people will test negative.  (This is what it means not to lose track of anybody.)  These facts are shown with fat arrows to indicate a lot of people pass their way.

[image]

It remains only to total those in each test group:

[image]

Observe that most of the people in the positive test group came from the disease-free population, because so many people do not have the disease.  Being able to **see** this is the point of the exercise. Unless you are good at math, the algebra only obscures this important realization.

You may read off the answer:

> Out of every million people who are tested, expect that $20,194$ will test positive.  The chance of a positive test therefore is $$P(T)=\frac{20194}{1000000}=0.020194=2.0194\%.$$

Comment: I sincerely appreciate you taking the time to write out your response. I do understand how to do it this method as well as the intuition behind it. I'm just curious as to why the algebraic method that I am using is not working.

Comment: Run through this result and turn it into algebra, then, to see where your algebra fails.